# How to pass previous trained model as a paramter in arima function in python?

Tags: python, r, time-series, arima

I am trying to do multistep forecasting using arima models in python. I found a good piece of code in R. It looks that in R ARIMA function we can pass pre-trained model as input as done in code  refit <- Arima(x, model=fit). But I can not find how to pass a model inside ARIMA function in python. Also i cant understand how to write the last line in python which is fc[i] <- forecast(refit, h=h)$mean[h] Below is the whole code snippet

```
train <- window(hsales,end=1989.99)
test <- window(hsales,start=1990)
n <- length(test) - h + 1
fit <- auto.arima(train)
fc <- ts(numeric(n), start=1990+(h-1)/12, freq=12)
for(i in 1:n)
{

  x <- window(hsales, end=1989.99 + (i-1)/12)
  refit <- Arima(x, model=fit)
  fc[i] <- forecast(refit, h=h)$mean[h]
}´´´
```